# rails 3 select control from nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models user and team.  a team can have many users each users belong to a team.

team_id is a column in my user table as a fk.

I want to have a select drop down on my create user form that has all my teams team_id in it.

This code does what I want BUT

```
 <%= f.fields_for :teams do |builder| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :team_id, "Select Team For User" %>
        <%= builder.collection_select :team_initials, Team.all, :id, :team_initials %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

it does not try to add the id value to a user.  here is the error

```
    Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxx",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"brand new",
 "email"=>"test1@test.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "teams"=>{"team_initials"=>"27"}},
 "commit"=>"Create my account"}
```

It complains that it cant add to the team model.

All I want to do is grab the ID of all existing teams for my create user form so when you crate a user you can select that users team.

The reason I have team_initials above is I was trying to use a more user friendly field for select but still user team Id as the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. The `fields_for` mechanism is for setting values in the associated model. I think all you're trying to do is make the association.

So you can lose the `fields_for` line and then this section:

```
builder.collection_select :team_initials, Team.all, :id, :team_initials
```

Should be:

```
f.collection_select :team_id, Team.all, :id, :team_initials
```

I'm looking here for my info on collection_select since I don't know it off the top of my head:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

I think this will change this parameter from `"teams"=>{"team_initials"=>"27"}},` to `"team_id"=>"27",`

I hope that fixes it.

Comment: this worked great I was definitely over complicating it.  Almost to easy.  thanks